# C++: Replace raw pointers with shared and weak ptr

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I'm facing a design issue in my program.
I have to manage Nodes object which are part of a root ChainDescriptor.

Basically it looks like the following:

```
class ChainDescriptor
{
public:
    ~ChainDescriptor()
    {
        //delete the nodes in nodes...
    }

    void addNode(Node *);
    Node * getNode();

    const std::list<Node *>& getNodes() const;

    std::list<Node *> m_nodes;

};

class Node
{
public:
    Node(Node *parent);

    void addChild(Node *node);
    Node * getChild(const std::string& nodeName);

private:
    Node * m_parent;
    std::list<Node*> m_childs;
};
```

The ChainDescriptor class owns all the nodes and is responsible of deleting them.
But these classes need now to be used in another program, a GUI with undo/redo capabilities, with the problematic of the "ownership".
Before modifying the existing code in depth, I'm considering the different solutions:

- using `shared_ptr` and respective `list<shared_ptr<...> >`
- using `weak_ptr` and respective `list<weak_ptr<...> >`

In the example above, I don't really know where to use `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` properly.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What about [`boost::ptr_list`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_list.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `shared_ptr` for `m_childs` and `weak_ptr` for `m_parent`.

However, it might be still reasonable to retain the raw pointer to the parent `Node` and don't use any weak pointers at all. The safeguarding mechanism behind this is the invariant that non-null parent always exists.

Another option is using `shared_ptr` in `ChainDescriptor` only and retaining all raw pointers in `Node`. This approach avoids weak pointers and has a clean ownership policy (parent nodes own their children).

Weak pointers will help you to manage the memory automatically, but the backside of this are fuzzy ownership logic and performance penalties.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the option of raw pointers. I think they are the right tool to express the ownership situation of m_parent.

Comment: @Sergey, I agree.
I began to write a prototype in this direction.
ChainDescriptor will contain shared_ptr list. For the Node class, I began to write weak_ptr<Node> list but it's a bit tricky to search node in the list as no == operator is defined in weak_ptr.

Comment: Do you access parent via ``weak_ptr`` rarely? If so, ``weak_ptr`` is your best friend. If you need to access parent all the time, somewhere in your inner loop, think about raw pointers. They are not bad.

Comment: @Sergey, each node may have several parents actually ( it's a tree). The chain must be able to access the "upstream" nodes of a particular node at any moment. Thus, each node has 2 lists: the upstream nodes list and the child nodes. But if I use shared_ptr list for the upstream nodes, I got cyclic issues and mem leaks. Therefore I'm afraid I've to deal with different kinds of lists. list<shared_ptr> for the childs, and list<weak_ptr> or list<rawptr> for the upstream nodes ?

Comment: If you are sure the structure is persistent and parents are destroyed after children (and you'd better be), you can just live with raw pointers happily. Trust me.

Answer (score 3):

`shared_ptr` is owning smart pointer and `weak_ptr` is referencing smart pointer.

So in your situation I think the `ChainDescriptor` should use `shared_ptr` (it owns the nodes) and `Node` should use `weak_ptr` for `m_parent` (it only references it) and `shared_ptr` for `m_childs` (it owns them).

Comment: Could you explain the advantages of `weak_ptr` over a raw pointer for the parent?

Comment: Usage of `weak_ptr` is safe. Validity of raw pointers must be ensured by invariants (as described in Sergey's answer). Main problem of `weak_ptr` is its performance impact - nothing can compete with raw pointers if you need speed.

Comment: Usage of `weak_ptr` is complicated, and I don't see where it really adds any safety here.  And it's not just a question of speed, it's also a question of ease of use.  If `weak_ptr` protected against some sort of error that a programmer might actually make, that would be one thing.  But in this case, his code only supports a single parent, and deleting the parent will delete the child, so there's no case the pointer to parent can possibly be accessed once the parent has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The usual implementation would be for each node to have strong reference to its child (i.e. keeps them alive), and each child to have a weak reference back to the parent.

The reason for this is to avoid circular references. If only strong references were used, then you'd have a situation where the parent refcount never drops to zero (because the child has a reference), and the child refcount never drops to zero (because the parent has a reference).

I think your `ChainDescriptor` class is okay to use strong references here though.

Comment: The usual implementation would use raw pointers for the back pointers to the parent.  There's no need for a weak pointer here, since the ownership semantics guarantee that a child cannot outlive its parent.  And depending on the structure: if it is a DAG, child pointers must be shared, but otherwise, `unique_ptr` would do the job just as well, with much less complexity and overhead.

Comment: True... my thinking was that if there was a need for a `Node::getParent()` function at some point then you'd want it to return a full `shared_ptr`, in which case it would be easier to "upgrade" the held `weak_ptr` than to use `enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: @Tristan, sure I agree.
The ChainDescriptor contains the whole list of nodes. But if ChainDescriptor removes a node ( i.e. chainDesc.removeNode("blabla") ), it will remove it from the main list, but also from all other nodes having "blabla" as child.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to just replace raw pointers with some sort of smart
pointer will *in general* not work.  Smart pointers have 
different semantics than weak pointers, and usually, these
special semantics need to be taken into account at a higher
level.  The "cleanest" solution here is to add support for copy
in `ChainDescriptor`, implementing a deep copy.  (I'm supposing
here that you can clone `Node`, and that all of the `Node` are
always owned by a `ChainDescriptor`.)  Also, for undo, you may
need a deep copy anyway; you don't want modifications in the
active instance to modify the data saved for an undo.

Having said that, your nodes seem to be used to form a tree.  In
this case, `std::shared_ptr` will work, as long as 1) all `Node`
are always "owned" by either a `ChainDescriptor` or a parent
`Node`, and 2) the structure really is a forest, or at least
a collection of DAG (and, of course, you aren't making changes
in any of the saved instances).  If the structure is such that
cycles may occur, then you cannot use `shared_ptr` at this
level.  You might be able to abstract the list of nodes and the
trees into a separate implementation class, and have
`ChainDescriptor` keep a `shared_ptr` to this.

(FWIW: I used a reference counted pointer for the nodes in
a parse tree I wrote many years ago, and different instances
could share sub-trees.  But I designed it from the
start to use reference counted pointers.  And because of how the
tree was constructed, I was guaranteed that there could be no
cycles.)

Comment: Yes, a Node is always onwed by the Chain or parent Node. But if a Node is removed from the Chain (i.e. chain.removeNode("blabla"), then the mechanism should also remove it from the child lists of any node owning it.

Comment: @Zyend I don't know of any smart pointer which will do that.  You mean that you have to navigate to the parent, and remove the nodes from that as well?

Comment: @Zyend Also: what are you actually putting in the undo list, and how do you expect it to work when you make modifications in the original object?  From your description, I'm getting a very strong impression that you need deep copy.  (Presumably, the objects are not currently copyable.)